# KingFisher 5.0 crashing with EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION in Xcode 11.2

Tags: kingfisher, xcode11

I got Xcode 11.2 (beta and stable releases) since I updated iOS to 13.2. I have been using KingFisher with no errors and Suddenly it crashes with the error `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=1, subcode=0x210007)` in `ImageDownloader` line 169:

```swift
sessionDelegate.onReceiveSessionChallenge.delegate(on: self) { (self, invoke) in
            self.authenticationChallengeResponder?.downloader(self, didReceive: invoke.1, completionHandler: invoke.2)
        }
```

The culprit is this line of code in `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`:

```swift
cell.productImageView.kf.setImage(with: self.datasource[indexPath.row].imageUrl)
```

the value in: `self.datasource[indexPath.row].imageUrl` is http://sgfm.elcorteingles.es/SGFM/dctm/MEDIA03/201811/26/00118105700068____2__40x40.jpg

The [KingFisher 5 Migration guide](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/wiki/Kingfisher-5.0-Migration-Guide) says that this should work. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** A working (crashing) concept can be found at: https://github.com/juanjoseluisgarcia/kignfishertest.git

Comment: The same thing happens

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE:** [As per twitter](https://twitter.com/tcldr1/status/1190396639334285312?s=21) the solution to this and similar problems with Swift Package Manager in Xcode 11.2 is to go to the **target**, "Linker settings" and change "Dead Code Stripping" to **NO**

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/issues/1330) in Github. The issue is around the Package Manager in Xcode 11.2 They will need to update the linker for the Package Manager.